# Windows cannot log you on because your profile cannot be loaded

Tags: iis

My Application pools stop automatically and I am getting below errors in Application event log:

1) Windows cannot log you on because your profile cannot be loaded. Check that you are connected to the network, and that your network is functioning correctly.

DETAIL - Only part of a ReadProcessMemory or WriteProcessMemory request was completed.

2) Windows cannot copy file \?\C:\Users\Default\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\SQM\iesqmdata_setup0.sqm to location \?\C:\Users\TEMP.FEDERATED.000\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\SQM\iesqmdata_setup0.sqm. This error may be caused by network problems or insufficient security rights.

DETAIL - Access is denied.

NOTE: Both locations mentioned in the error do not exist neither does the .sqm file exists anywhere in the system

3) Windows cannot find the local profile and is logging you on with a temporary profile. Changes you make to this profile will be lost when you log off.

How do I fix this?

Comment: what kind of windows version are you using? Found some info about this error here:  [answers.microsoft.com](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/events-log-name-application-shows-user-account/2edc7bd2-2437-4981-ac7b-315308b56627)

Answer (score 1):

In my case `App pool user profile` is corrupted, so windows create new temp profile for that.

Check below folder exist in your machine then you have same problem.

```
C:\Users\TEMP.IIS APPPOOL
```

I follow below step then working fine to me.

- Find all folder have `*.bak` extension in below given registry path

  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList`
- Now check that folder have key is `ProfileImagePath` and value is `C:\Users\TEMP.IIS APPPOOL`
- Go to https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/947215 link and follow step given for correct corrupted user profile.